# GAE php app Push-to-Deploy failed

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy to GAE with the new Push-to-Deploy feature using git.
The deployment failed with this error:

> Deployment failed, details: { Failed to load application, while
>   scanning a simple key; could not found expected ':', none}

my app.yaml file:

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe = true
```

I couldn't find what the simple key means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this line in your `app.yaml` file:

```
threadsafe = true
```

To:

```
threadsafe: true
```

Comment: Best to set it to threadsafe: false because concurrent requests aren't currently supported in the PHP runtime.

Comment: Solved my problem on deployment

remote: Deployment failed: Deployment failed, details: { Failed to load application, threadsafe is a required field., none}