# GAE PHP Git Deploy

Tags: php, git, google-app-engine

Is there opportunity to deploy PHP-apps throw git pushing?

I do push in master-origin, can see sources in Console-SourceCode-Browse (and BitBucket), but Releases is empty (pipeline tuned-up). 
And i cant find where git-deploy logging are to debug.

But.. in https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy#setting_up_a_release_pipeline written "You can use Push-to-Deploy with applications in Java, Python and Go."

But in SOF [GAE php app Push-to-Deploy failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021835/gae-php-app-push-to-deploy-failed) written that it is working. I cant understand where is truth )

Summary,
Is PHP-apps can be deployed throw Git(BitBucket) pushing?
And where deployment logs are located?

Thank in advance for everybody!

PS: it is very necessary for deploying from web-ide like c9.io

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, you should be able to deploy your app engine code with git (I use it for several app-engine php projects).

A common mistake you might have is a mistake in one of your .yaml files. You will still be able to commit and push your changes, but your deployments will fail.

Here is the output from my terminal when I added some mistakes to my cron.yaml file and tried to push & deploy

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 336 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Storing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Processing commits: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Triggering release (if applicable)...
remote: View results at:https://console.developers.google.com/project/.....(retracted)
remote: Running...
remote: Created deployment: appengineid.pipelines...(retracted)
remote: Dispatched
remote: Deployment failed. Details: Deployment failed, details: { Failed to load application, Line 3, column 26: Unable to find property 'alsdkjf;alksdfj  schedule' on class: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.CronYamlReader$CronYaml, none
To https://source.developers.google.com/p/AppEngineId/r/default
8190aea..2dc6945  master -> master
```

You should be able to see a similar error when you push, or you might not have git repository set up correctly.